java jlink with a lot of automatic modules and/or unamed modules
I created a module for the application I am developing (MyApp.jar)
This application depends on many unnamed or automatic modules.
How can I generate a jlink image with these unnamed or automatic modules?
I tried to call a transormation for each module
modularize.bat commons-io-2.10.0.jar org.apache.commons.io 

see modularize.bat script
set _jar_=%1
set _name_=%2
jdeps --ignore-missing-deps --generate-module-info target\libs target\libs\%_jar_%
type target\libs\%_name_%\module-info.java
javac --patch-module %_name_%=target\libs\%_jar_% target\libs\%_name_%\module-info.java
jar uf target\libs\%_jar_% -C target\libs\%_name_% module-info.class
rmdir /S /Q target\libs\%_name_%

Finally, jlink creates a image but it doesn't work.
Do you have an idea ?
I have a lot of warnings during modularization (ex :Warning: --ignore-missing-deps specified. Missing dependencies from org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient are ignored)
This is the list of all dependancies;
checker-qual-3.12.0.jar
commons-codec-1.11.jar
commons-io-2.10.0.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
error_prone_annotations-2.7.1.jar
failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
flatlaf-3.4.jar
flatlaf-intellij-themes-3.4.jar
google-api-client-1.33.0.jar
google-api-services-drive-v3-rev197-1.25.0.jar
google-api-services-oauth2-v2-rev157-1.25.0.jar
google-http-client-1.41.0.jar
google-http-client-apache-v2-1.41.0.jar
google-http-client-gson-1.41.0.jar
google-http-client-jackson2-1.33.0.jar
google-oauth-client-1.32.1.jar
google-oauth-client-java6-1.33.0.jar
google-oauth-client-jetty-1.33.0.jar
grpc-context-1.27.2.jar
gson-2.8.9.jar
guava-31.0.1-jre.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
httpclient-4.5.13.jar
httpcore-4.4.15.jar
j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
jackson-core-2.10.0.jar
jsch-0.2.11.jar
jsr305-3.0.2.jar
junit-4.13.2.jar
listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar
log4j-api-2.23.1.jar
log4j-core-2.23.1.jar
opencensus-api-0.28.0.jar
opencensus-contrib-http-util-0.28.0.jar


You haven't shown use of jlink nor the error messages the new runtime image shows when you try to use the app. That would give you details of what classes are missed out and need feeding back into your jlink command line / module-info

This is the jlink command used
jlink --module-path target\libs --add-modules mymodule,jdk.crypto.ec --output dist   --launcher mymodule=mymodule/com.mymodule.App
This command works but during the execution, some errors appears (unable to load classes, etc...

The exact error is
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory (in module com.google.api.client.json.jackson2) cannot access class com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory (in module com.google.api.client) because module com.google.api.client.json.jackson2 does not read module com.google.api.client

Try setting the class-path and/or module-path when executing jdeps.

I dont understand what is missing ?

Based on the "does not read module" error, my guess is the module-info files you're generating are missing needed requires directives because the dependencies are not found. The jdeps invocation would fail if not for --ignore-missing-deps. Try setting the --class-path and/or --module-path to see if that helps.

It seems impossible to specify class-path with --generate-module-info (see jdeps docs)
--generate-module-info <dir>  Generate module-info.java under the specified                                 directory. The specified JAR files will be                                 analyzed. This option cannot be used with                                 --dot-output or --class-path.

And what about --module-path?

Indeed it's not possible to create a jlink image containing non-modularized jars. However, you can create an image with only the java modules that your application needs and then work with the class- and/or module path. An example workflow to work only with the class path (will also work even if your app is modularized).
Given a directory jars containing all application's jars, first figure out which java modules are needed with jdeps:
jdeps --multi-release 21 --module-path jars --print-module-deps --ignore-missing-deps jars/* | grep -v '^Warning: split package'

This will output something like this:
java.base,java.x,java.y,...

Now create the jlink image:
jlink --add-modules java.base,java.x,java.y,... --output jvm

To run the application:
jvm/bin/java --class-path 'jars/*' package.MainClass

If your main jar is modularized and you want to put it on the module path, you have to put it in a separate directory together with it's real and automatic module dependencies. You can use the jli script to do this for you:
jli -l jars -i -o -m main.module

This will create a directory jli containing three directories:

jvm: the jlink image
cp: directory with jars to put on the class path
mp: directory with jars to put on the module path

To run the application:
cd jli
jvm/bin/java --class-path 'cp/*' --module-path mp -m main.module/package.MainClass

Note it's also possible to use jli for a non-modularized app (the original scenario in the post), which is a bit easier than excuting both the jdeps and jlink command, and it adds some extra options ot the jlink command by default, to optimize the image size:
jli -l jars -i
jli/jvm/bin/java --class-path 'jars/*' package.MainClass


Many thanks for your comment
